# What is the difference between PS1 and PROMPT_COMMAND?

Tags: bash, prompt

While taking a look at [this awesome thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20161214154424/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103857/what-is-your-favorite-bash-prompt) I noticed that some examples use

```
PS1="Blah Blah Blah"
```

and some use

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="Blah Blah Blah"
```

(and some use both) when setting the prompt in a Bash shell. What is the difference between the two? A Stack Overflow search and even a bit of broader Google searching aren't getting me results, so even a link to the right place to look for the answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From the GNU Bash documentation page ([Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
    If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before
    the printing of each primary prompt ($PS1).
```

I never used it, but I could have used this back when I only had *sh*.

Answer (score 82):

[PROMPT_COMMAND](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html) can contain ordinary Bash statements whereas the PS1 variable can also contain the special characters, such as '\h' for hostname, in the variable.

For example, here is my Bash prompt that uses both PROMPT_COMMAND and PS1. The Bash code in PROMPT_COMMAND works out what Git branch you might be in and displays that at the prompt, along with the exit status of the last run process, hostname and basename of the [pwd](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html).

The variable RET stores the return value of the last executed program. This is convenient to see if there was an error and the error code of the last program I ran in the terminal. Note the outer ' surrounding the entire PROMPT_COMMAND expression. It includes PS1 so that this variable is reevaluated each time the PROMPT_COMMAND variable is evaluated.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='RET=$?;\
  BRANCH="";\
  ERRMSG="";\
  if [[ $RET != 0 ]]; then\
    ERRMSG=" $RET";\
  fi;\
  if git branch &>/dev/null; then\
    BRANCH=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep \* |  cut -d " " -f 2);\
  fi;
PS1="$GREEN\u@\h $BLUE\W $CYAN$BRANCH$RED$ERRMSG \$ $LIGHT_GRAY";'
```

Example output looks like this in a non-Git directory:

```
sashan@dhcp-au-122 Documents  $ false
sashan@dhcp-au-122 Documents  1 $
```

And in a Git directory you see the branch name:

```
sashan@dhcp-au-122 rework mybranch $
```

### Update

After reading the comments and Bob's answer, I think that writing it as he describes is better. It's more maintainable than what I originally wrote above, where the PS1 variable is set inside the PROMPT_COMMAND, which itself is a super complicated string that is evaluated at runtime by Bash.

It works, but it's more complicated than it needs to be. To be fair, I wrote that PROMPT_COMMAND for myself about 10 years ago and it worked and didn't think too much about it.

For those curious as to how I've amended my things, I've basically put the code for the PROMPT_COMMAND in a separate file (as Bob described) and then echo the string that I intend to be PS1:

```
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
PURPLE="\[\033[0;35m\]"
BROWN="\[\033[0;33m\]"
LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
LIGHT_BLUE="\[\033[1;34m\]"
LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
LIGHT_CYAN="\[\033[1;36m\]"
LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
LIGHT_PURPLE="\[\033[1;35m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[1;33m\]"
WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
RESTORE="\[\033[0m\]" #0m restores to the terminal's default colour

if [ -z $SCHROOT_CHROOT_NAME ]; then
    SCHROOT_CHROOT_NAME=" "
fi
BRANCH=""
ERRMSG=""
RET=$1
if [[ $RET != 0 ]]; then
    ERRMSG=" $RET"
fi
if which git &>/dev/null; then
    BRANCH=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep \* |  cut -d " " -f 2)
else
    BRANCH="(git not installed)"
fi
echo "${GREEN}\u@\h${SCHROOT_CHROOT_NAME}${BLUE}\w \
${CYAN}${BRANCH}${RED}${ERRMSG} \$ $RESTORE"
```

And in my *.bashrc* file:

```
function prompt_command {
    RET=$?
    export PS1=$(~/.bash_prompt_command $RET)
}
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Comment: You could shorten one of your lines: `if git branch &>/dev/null ; then\ `. It redirects both stdout and stderr to /dev/null. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: There is no need to *export* `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: I think ceving's comment is very much true for this answer too: `Don't set PS1 in PROMPT_COMMAND! Set variables in PROMPT_COMMAND and use them in PS1`

Comment: I do not see a reason, why changing `PS1` online within `PROMPT_COMMAND` is disadvantageous. It is perfect useful code. In contrast to Bob's answer down, the `PS1` variable was correctly constructed. This allows a much more sophisticated bash prompt depending on your actual situation.

Comment: @ChristianWolf construction of `PS1` inside `PROMPT_COMMAND` serves no purpose. it is an example how not to do it. construct `PS1` once in `.bash_profile`, just use single quotes instead of double quotes, so that variable substitutions will be evaluated during each prompt.

Comment: @pal if I try it as you suggest with `PS1` in single quotes` in `.bash_profile` I get a prompt like this:
`@deimos:\[\033[0;35m\] \[\033[0;34m\]/home/xsasgov     \[\033[0;36m\]\[\033[0;31m\] $ \[\033[0;37m\]`. For some reason my colours don't work. How do I fix that?

Comment: @pal - don't worry I think I've fixed it why the colours didn't appear.

Comment: @pal No I cannot confirm this. Assume you want to adjust `PS1` depending on your current working path. Then you have to change `PS1` for each new line of your command prompt, where `PROMT_COMMAND` matches perfectly. One example: **If** you are in a git working folder, put another `PS1` style that shows the current branch as well.

Comment: One reason to avoid setting PS1 in PROMPT_COMMAND is that you can never reset it on the fly if you do, because it will be constantly reset. Not incredibly common, but still confusing when it happens.

Comment: i like this pattern but agree with the issues with setting PS1 from PROMPT_COMMAND - there's no reason we can't do something like `PROMPT_COMMAND="PROMPT_COMMAND_OUT=$(script_or_whatever)"; PS1="stuff and ${PROMPT_COMMAND_OUT} and things \$"`

Comment: @pal OMG the double-quote vs single-quote was killing me. Thanks for the explicit call out.

Answer (score 56):

The difference is that `PS1` is the actual prompt string used, and `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a command that is executed just before the prompt. If you want the simplest, most flexible way of building a prompt, try this:

Put this in your *.bashrc* file:

```
function prompt_command {
  export PS1=$(~/bin/bash_prompt)
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

Then write a script (Bash, [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), or [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29): your choice), and place it in file *~/bin/bash_prompt*.

The script can use any information it likes to construct a prompt. This is much simpler, IMO, because you don't have to learn the somewhat baroque substitution language that was developed just for the `PS1` variable.

You might think that you could do the same by simply setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` directly to *~/bin/bash_prompt*, and setting `PS1` to the empty string.

This at first appears to work, but you soon discover that the readline code expects `PS1` to be set to the actual prompt, and when you scroll backwards in history, things get messed up as a result.

This workaround causes `PS1` to always reflect the latest prompt (since the function sets the actual `PS1` variable used by the invoking instance of the shell), and this makes readline and command history work fine.

Comment: Don't set `PS1` in `PROMPT_COMMAND`! Set variables in `PROMPT_COMMAND` and use them in `PS1`. Otherwise you you will loose the ability to use the `PS1` escape sequences like `\u` or `\h`. You have to reinvent them in `PROMPT_COMMAND`. That might be possible but it is not possible to work around the lose of `\[` and `\]` which mark the beginning and end of non printable characters. This means you can not use colors without confusing the terminal about the length of the prompt. And this confuses `readline` when editing a command spawning two lines. In the end you have a big mess on the screen.

Comment: @ceving True that! One may use PROMPT_COMMAND to change the **format** of your PS1 and get the best of both worlds

Comment: `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed before printing `PS1`. I see no problems setting `PS1` from inside `PROMPT_COMMAND`, because after `PROMPT_COMMAND` is finished, the shell will print `PS1`, which was modified from `PROMPT_COMMAND` (or in this case, inside `prompt_command`) ?

Comment: Warning: PROMPT_COMMAND generally should not be used to print characters directly to the prompt. Characters printed outside of PS1 are not counted by Bash, which will cause it to incorrectly place the cursor and clear characters. Either use PROMPT_COMMAND to set PS1 or look at embedding commands. ([Arch Wiki Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#PROMPT_COMMAND))

Comment: i don't get it why everyone tries to do some  tricks in PROMPT_COMMAND instead of just using command substitution in PS1
```export PS1='$(~/bin/bash_prompt)'``` does same thing bug looks sane

Comment: also while @ceving is correct regarding confusion, he is wrong regarding losing escape sequences. just try `PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="\u \h \$"'`. it does not mean you should do that, it would be pointless waste of resources

Comment: @ceving bash and readline support \001 and \002 instead of \[ and \], so this is not a problem.

Comment: @Ivanq In fact, `\[` is just a prompt-specific alias for `\001`, just like `\u` is a prompt-specific alias for `$USER`.

Answer (score 16):

From [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> `PROMPT_COMMAND`
>
> If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.
>
> `PS1`
>
> The value of this parameter is expanded (see PROMPTING below) and used as the primary prompt string. The default value is ''\s-\v\$ ''.

If you simply want to set the prompt string, using `PS1` alone is enough:

```
PS1='user \u on host \h$ '
```

If you want to do something else just before printing the prompt, use `PROMPT_COMMAND`. For example, if you want to sync cached writes to disk, you can write:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='sync'
```

Comment: You can also set the title of the terminal from `PS1` without needing `PROMPT_COMMAND`, as the sequence that set the title can be included in `PS1` wrapped with `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: @dolmen All right. Then let's do something else, such as dynamically setting an environment variable.

Comment: @Cyker you can dynamically set environment variable in `PS1`, it just will be set in subshell, so you can't get its value back. but your example is trivial `PS1='$(sync)user \u on host \h$ '`

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, so to try to really nail this down:

- `PROMPT_COMMAND` is a handy **Bash** convenience variable/function, but there is, strictly speaking, nothing that cannot also be done using `PS1` alone, correct?

I mean, if one wants to **set** *another* variable with scope outside the prompt: depending on the shell, that variable would probably need to be declared first outside `$PS1` or (worst case) one might have to get fancy with something waiting on a FIFO prior to calling `$PS1` (and armed again at the end of `$PS1`); the `\u` `\h` might cause some trouble, particularly if you're using some fancy regex; but otherwise: one can accomplish anything `PROMPT_COMMAND` can by using command substitution within `$PS1` (and, maybe in corner cases, explicit subshells)?

Right?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that

- if you output an incomplete line from `PROMPT_COMMAND`, it will screw your Bash prompt
- `PS1` substitutes `\H` and friends
- `PROMPT_COMMAND` runs its contents, and `PS1` uses its contents as the prompt.

`PS1` does variable expansion and command substitution at each prompt. There isn't any need to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to assign a value to `PS1` or to run arbitrary code. You can easily do `export PS1='$(uuidgen) $RANDOM'` once in file `.bash_profile`. Just use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I spent so much time on this I just wanted to share what worked for me. I looked at a lot of the SO posts about PROMPT_COMMAND and PS1 and tried many combinations of single quotes, double quotes, calling functions... I could not get the prompt to update each time without printing control characters or the literal expanded but not processed prompt string, or without just setting PS1 in PROMPT_COMMAND as we are advised not to do. My problem was setting variables (colors) that contained control characters; these had to be hard-coded after the variable name in PS1. PROMPT_COMMAND is set to a function that sets variables and they are used (escaped) in a double-quoted PS1 string. This is for a powerline-style prompt that changes colors with each command.

```bash
icon1=#unicode powerline char like
#these: https://github.com/ryanoasis/powerline-extra-symbols#glyphs
icon2=#same

#array of ANSI colors. 2 for rgb mode then the rgb values
#then 'm' without '\]' control character. these are from
#the solarized theme https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/
declare -a colors=(
  "2;220;50;47m"
  "2;203;75;22m"
  "2;181;137;0m"
  "2;133;153;0m"
  "2;42;161;152m"
  "2;38;139;210m"
  "2;108;113;196m"
  "2;211;54;130m"
  "2;0;43;54m"
  "2;7;54;66m"
  "2;88;110;117m"
  "2;101;123;131m"
  "2;131;148;150m"
  "2;147;161;161m"
)
#outside of vars set in PROMPT_COMMAND it's ok to have control chars
LEN=${#colors[@]}
BG="\[\e[48;"#set bg color
FG="\[\e[38;"#set fg color
TRANSP="1m\]"#transparency
BASE2="2;238;232;213m\]"#fg (text) color

myfunc(){
  RAND=$(($RANDOM % $LEN))
  COLOR1=${colors[$RAND]}
  COLOR2=${colors[($RAND + 1) % $LEN]}
  COLOR3=${colors[($RAND + 2) % $LEN]}
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=myfunc

#note double quotes and escaped COLOR vars followed by hard-coded '\]' control chars
PS1="$BG$TRANSP$FG\$COLOR1\]$icon1$BG\$COLOR1\]$FG$TRANSP$BG\$COLOR1\]$FG$BASE2 
[username hard-coded in unicode] $BG\$COLOR2\]$FG\$COLOR1\]$icon2$BG\$COLOR2\]$FG$BASE2 
\w $BG\$COLOR3\]$FG\$COLOR2\]$icon2$BG\$COLOR3\]$FG$BASE2 [more unicode] 
\[\e[0m\]$FG\$COLOR3\]$icon2\[\e[0m\] "
```

That ought to get you going!