# OSX Bash prompt displaying git status

Tags: git, bash, environment-variables, command-prompt, prompt

I'm trying to convince my bash prompt to add coloration when my current repo has uncommitted changes of any sort.

```
git_status() {
    printf "%s : %s" $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) $(git rev-parse --short=10 HEAD)
}

has_changed() {
    if [[ -n `git diff HEAD` ]]; then
        printf " - %s Δ %s"  ${Green} ${Color_Off}
    fi
}

PS1=${Purple}"\w"${Color_Off}" @ \$(git_status) \$(has_changed)\n \$ "
```

This partially works, but the has_changed function returns escaped characters rather than colors:

`~/projects/project @ master : 8675309  - \033[0;32m Δ \033[0m`

Version of bash: `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`, on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: If you're interested in a third-party prompt, I highly recommend [liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt). Among other things, it puts git status, current branch, etc. into your prompt.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the status into your prompt you would need to use the [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) environment variable.

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> ```
> If set, the value is interpreted as a command to execute before the printing of each primary prompt ($PS1).
> ```

Here is a simple example (tested and works) which you could adapt to your needs:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne $(if [[ -n `git diff HEAD` ]]; then echo true; fi)'
```

Also related: [What is the difference between PS1 and PROMPT_COMMAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058325/what-is-the-difference-between-ps1-and-prompt-command)