# Why doesn't my prompt change when I activate a virtualenv?

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, command-prompt, virtualenvwrapper

When I activate a Python virtualenv with `workon`, my prompt does not change to identify the environment.

I've confirmed that my `activate` script contains

```
if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="$PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) $PS1"
    fi
    export PS1
fi
```

and that `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` is unset.

Why would this be happening and what can I do to fix it?

---

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

---

I've got some fancy footwork going on in my `.bash_profile`, but I don't see why any of this should matter once the prompt has been set:

```
declare PSCOLORPATH='\[\e[0;33m\]'
declare PSCOLORPROMPT='\[\e[1;32m\]'
declare PSCOLORHOST='\[\e[0;32m\]'
declare PSCOLOROOT='\[\e[1;31m\]'
declare PSCOLOREND='\[\e[m\]'
#echo $PSCOLORPATH
if [ $SSH_FLAG -eq 1 ] ; then
    declare PSHOST='\h:'
else
    declare PSHOST=''
fi
if [ $IS_SU -eq 1 ] ; then
    PS1_INFO="$PSCOLOROOT[SU] $PSCOLORHOST$PSHOST$PSCOLORPATH\w"
else
    PS1_INFO="$PSCOLORHOST$PSHOST$PSCOLORPATH\w"
fi
PS1_PROMPT="$PSCOLORPROMPT \\$ $PSCOLOREND"
declare -x PS1="$PS1_INFO$PS1_PROMPT"
#declare -x PS1="$PSCOLORHOST$PSHOST$PSCOLORPATH\w $PSCOLORPROMPT\\$ $PSCOLOREND"
declare -x PS2="$PSCOLORPROMPT> $PSCOLOREND"
declare -x PS4="$PSCOLORPROMPT+ $PSCOLOREND"

source $(brew --repository)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh

GIT_PS1_HIDE_IF_PWD_IGNORED=1
PS1_NORMAL=$PS1
_gitprompt () {
    if [ "$1" = "off" ]; then
        GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=; GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=; GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=; GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=;
        PS1="$PS1_NORMAL"; PROMPT_COMMAND=; 
    else
        if [ "$1" = "verbose" ]; then
            GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"; GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1; GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=1; GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=;
            PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "$PS1_INFO" "$PS1_PROMPT"';           
        elif [ "$1" = "color" ]; then
            GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=; GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=; GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=; GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1;
            PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "$PS1_INFO$PSCOLOREND" "$PS1_PROMPT"';            
        else
            GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=; GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=; GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=; GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=;
            PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "$PS1_INFO" "$PS1_PROMPT"';
        fi
    fi
}
alias gitprompt="_gitprompt"

gitprompt verbose
```

---

FWIW, `set -x; source /path/to/activate` gives:

```
+ __git_ps1 '\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w' '\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ local exit=126
+ local pcmode=no
+ local detached=no
+ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
+ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
+ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
+ case "$#" in
+ pcmode=yes
+ ps1pc_start='\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w'
+ ps1pc_end='\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ printf_format=' (%s)'
+ PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ local ps1_expanded=yes
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -z '3.2.57(1)-release' ']'
+ shopt -q promptvars
+ local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
+ git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD
+ repo_info=
+ rev_parse_exit_code=128
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ return 126
~ $ set -x; source ~/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/zoot/bin/activate
+ set -x
+ source /Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/zoot/bin/activate
+ deactivate nondestructive
+ unset -f pydoc
+ '[' -z _ ']'
+ PATH=/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
+ export PATH
+ unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
+ hash -r
+ '[' -z _ ']'
+ PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ export PS1
+ unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
+ unset VIRTUAL_ENV
+ '[' '!' nondestructive = nondestructive ']'
+ VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/zoot
+ export VIRTUAL_ENV
+ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
+ PATH=/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/zoot/bin:/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
+ export PATH
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ '[' x '!=' x ']'
+ basename /Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/venvs/zoot
+ PS1='(zoot) \[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ export PS1
+ alias pydoc
+ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
+ hash -r
+ __git_ps1 '\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w' '\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ local exit=0
+ local pcmode=no
+ local detached=no
+ local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
+ local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
+ local 'printf_format= (%s)'
+ case "$#" in
+ pcmode=yes
+ ps1pc_start='\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w'
+ ps1pc_end='\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ printf_format=' (%s)'
+ PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'
+ local ps1_expanded=yes
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -z '3.2.57(1)-release' ']'
+ shopt -q promptvars
+ local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
+ git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD
+ repo_info=
+ rev_parse_exit_code=128
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ return 0
```

Comment: What is the output from `echo "$PS1"`? Is `_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1` defined? What happens if you activate the virtualenv with `set -x`?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: Before and after activating a virtual env, `echo "$PS1"` gives <code>\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]</code>; and `_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1 ` is the same. How do I activate an virtualenv with `set -x`?

Comment: `set -x; . ./path/to/activate` (might produce a lot of output)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: Output of `set -x; . ./path/to/activate` added to question.

Comment: You forgot the period before `./path/to/activate`. To make it easier: `set -x; source ./path/to/activate` (`source` is an alias for `.`)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: Fixed, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `.bash_profile` you are calling `gitprompt verbose` that in turn is setting:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "$PS1_INFO" "$PS1_PROMPT"'
```

I don't know what `__git_ps1` is, but from the output of `set -x; source ...` I can tell that it is the culprit:

```
+ hash -r  # <<< This is the last command executed by the 'activate' script
+ __git_ps1 '\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w' '\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'  # <<< This is PROMPT_COMMAND being called
...
+ PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[1;32m\] \$ \[\e[m\]'  # <<< This is PS1 getting restored
...
```

Here you have a few options, choose the one you prefer:

- modify `activate` and add a line to unset `PROMPT_COMMAND`;
- modify `__git_ps1` (if you can) so that it doesn't touch `PS1` when `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set;
- if you can't modify `__git_ps1`, then write a wrapper around it;
- manually unset `PROMPT_COMMAND` before entering a virtualenv;
- avoid calling `gitprompt` in your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Note: I've updated the output I see from `et -x; source ...` (there was a lot of garbage in the earlier version).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: that garbage was actually useful :)

Comment: It looks like `PROMPT_COMMAND` [is the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3058366/656912), but I'm not sure how to address that (since virtualenv uses `PS1`).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: I provided a few options. If you need help with any of them, just ask

Comment: This is really a bug/limitation in virtualenv. It should check whether `PROMPT_COMMAND` is in use and use that instead of `PS1` if it is. All I can do is `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` whenever I start a virtualenv. That needs to happen early in every `activate` though. Is there a way to achieve that? (In fact I'd like to unset and it then and restore it when I deactivate.)

Comment: You can do that by editing `activate` and `deactivate`

Comment: For each virtualenv?

Comment: FWIW, I've modified the `PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 ...` lines in my profile to `PROMPT_COMMAND='__venv_prefix; __git_ps1 ...`, where I've defined `__venv_prefix` as a shell function that (if appropriate) does `printf "(basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\")"`. This solves the problem, though it does cause some extra hesitation when the prompt is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Putting together @orome and @Andrea discussed:

I added to following to my bash script:

```
__venv_prefix()
{
    printf "$CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER"
}

# git color hint branch name
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__venv_prefix; __git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "'
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
```

It shows the conda env prefix when it is activated, git branch suffix when in a git repo, and both conda prefix and git suffix when both conditions are met.

EDIT: The above config has an issue that it does show conda environment on tab completion. The config below doesn't have the issue:

```
parse_git_branch() 
{
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[01;33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[01;34m\] \$\[\033[0m\] "
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was annoying me so I added the following aliases to my .bash_aliases after seeing [Andrea Corbellini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913824/andrea-corbellini)'s answer:

```
alias act="unset PROMPT_COMMAND && source ./.venv/bin/activate" 
alias dact="deactivate && export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command"
```

I always use the same directory name (.venv) so this works fine for me.  Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If `PROMPT_COMMAND` is overriding your `PS1` in bash, you can fix your prompt command function to be virtual environment aware:

```
my_prompt_command() {
    # ...do all your work to set PS1 here...

    if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]; then
        PS1="(venv) $PS1"
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=my_prompt_command
```

Activate also sets/uses `$VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT`, allowing some customization of how the prompt is modified. For example, instead of the above, I use a custom script to launch a virtual environment in a subshell:

```
venv=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -path '*/venv' -o -path '*/.venv' | head -n1)
if [[ -z "$venv" ]]; then
    bash -lic "source $venv/bin/activate; VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT='(bash:$venv)'; exec bash"
fi
```

This determines a valid virtual environment directory, creates a subshell, activates the virtual environment in the subshell, and sets the prompt to `"(bash:venv) $PS1"`. The `bash:` prefix in the prompt reminds me its a subshell so I can just `exit` and my original shell environment is untouched. The `VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT` allows me to override the default set by `venv/bin/activate`.

The script can do other things allowing some flexibility. For example mine automatically chooses to either source the venv or launch it in a subshell, and gives a different prompt prefix in either case.

Example:

```
myprompt$ which activate
$HOME/bin/activate   # I call my script activate and put it in the path

myprompt$ activate
(venv) myprompt$ ...
(venv) myprompt$ deactivate
myprompt$

myprompt$ bash activate
(bash:venv) myprompt$ ...
(bash:venv) myprompt$ exit
myprompt$
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution I can find relies on understanding the internals of `.venv/bin/activate`

Since `activate` sets / `deactivate` unsets `VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT`, you can rely on this variable existing / not existing in your shell when setting `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

```bash
# Prompt command
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "$VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT$PROMPT_BEFORE" "$PROMPT_AFTER"'
```