# Invoke a function before command execution

Tags: bash

> **PROMPT_COMMAND**
>
> If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each
>   primary prompt.

We have shell variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` to specify the command to run before prompt shows up, namely, just right after the execution of the command we typed in.

But I didn't find the counterpart which I expect to let us run a command right after we hit enter but **before the execution of the command we typed in**.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Would you accept "No, there isn't" as an answer?  :-)

Comment: Yes, with a short WHY would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `trap` command , from `man trap`

> If a SIGNAL_SPEC is DEBUG, ARG is executed before every simple command.

The idea is pretty straightforward: if you run :

```
trap "echo command" DEBUG
```

Then Bash will run echo command before it executes each subsequent command

```
~$ pwd
command
/home
~$ echo Bye
command
Bye
```

More details [here](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/xterm-titles-with-bash.html).

Comment: DOH! You win. I'll delete my answer. :-)

Comment: @ghoti, no, I've read you answer ,and I like it. Would you re-post it here, of course you can make some  change.

Comment: I agree with @dotc your answer seems to be helpful for OP you can edit it and add exemples , I'll test the command and edit my answer too when i find some time.

Answer (score 2):

As @storm identified there is indeed a way to do this, for the specific functionality you mentioned in your question. See [storm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49811254/1072112).

It seems that what you're looking for is a set of "hooks" to allow you to add functionality to different parts of the shell. As fun as it sounds, bash doesn't have much of that.

The purpose of `PROMPT_COMMAND` is generally considered to be to set up stuff that will be used by your prompt. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3058325/1072112) has some answers that demonstrate how it might be used for this. Of course, you can use it for other things (it's a hook after all), but the fact that it gets executed *before your prompt* kind of relates it to your prompt.

If you decide to trap for DEBUG, you should be aware that the trap doesn't follow you into functions, but a trap set within a function follows you back into the calling shell:

```
$ function red { trap "echo world" DEBUG; echo "RED"; echo "RED"; }
$ function blue { echo "BLUE"; echo "BLUE"; }
$ trap "echo hello" DEBUG
$ red
hello
world
RED
world
RED
$ blue
world
BLUE
BLUE
```

If you want a trap like this to be local to the function, you must define the function as a subshell, for instance:

```
$ red() ( trap "echo world" DEBUG; echo "RED"; echo "RED" )
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$ function red { ( trap "echo world" DEBUG; echo "RED"; echo "RED" ); }
```

I don't see this trap-within-a-function behaviour documented anywhere, and it seems a little approximate to me. I wouldn't be surprised if it changed in future versions of bash.

I can't speak for Chet, but I doubt we'll be seeing much hook functionality get added to bash 4. No idea what new functionality might be in the works for future versions.

Comment: ++ for functions example

Comment: Yes, 'trap set within a function follows you back into the calling shell' just confused me. You explained well, thanks a lot.

Comment: Since @storm gave the idea, I would like to give the credit to him. However, I appreciate your answer. It's very helpful.