# Commands called during git bash command

Tags: bash, git

Every time I type cd in git bash on windows I get the following text back:

```
$ cd Documents/
which: no bundle in (/c/Users/nfgal/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/nfgal/bin:/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:/c/Program Files/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Users/nfgal/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cmd:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/130/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/130/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/140/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Autodesk Shared:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/120/Tools/Binn:/c/Ruby26-x64/bin:/c/Users/nfgal/.cargo/bin:/c/Users/nfgal/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/MinGW/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2/bin:/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3:/c/Program Files/heroku/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/c/Users/nfgal/.rvm/bin:/c/Users/nfgal/.rvm/bin)
```

It changes the directory, but it is calling which every time for some reason. This has been happening since I installed rvm. Here is my ~/.bashrc file:

```
cd /d/
alias ll='ls -l'
alias refresh='source ~/.bash_profile'
alias subl='/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe'
alias bashrc='subl /c/Users/nfgal/.bashrc'
alias repos='cd /d/repos'
```

Here is my ~/.bash_profile

```
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

~/profile is empty

Comment: What's the output of `type cd`?

Comment: Same as when I type cd Documents

Comment: Can we see the result of `echo $SHELL; type -a cd`

Comment: What's in `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: @torek Updating post to show ~/.bash_profile and ~/.profile

Comment: Huh, well, the `. ~/.bashrc` looks like infinite recursion: .bashrc reads .bash_profile which reads .bashrc which reads ...  Other than that, this is mysterious. Perhaps there's a system `/etc/profile` that does something?

Comment: I just removed stuff in ~/.bash_profile and it works now thanks

Comment: Where does bashrc read bash_profile? That is a command to open up bashrc in sublime to edit it I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove lines inside ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

It could be [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3058366/7976758). Try `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` and if there is a command unset it with `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`. Look the variable up in your `~/.bash_profile` if it's not in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Got nothing when typing echo $PROMPT_COMMAND