# Adding a bash command to PS1

Tags: bash, command-prompt

I would like to add a bash command into the command prompt. Let's say date -R, to print the current time.
How would I go about doing this, while also making sure it doesn't just stick to whatever time comes up when the command is added to PS1? (ergo, when one presses enter on the command line, the prompt updates as well with the new value of the command)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between PS1 and PROMPT\_COMMAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058325/what-is-the-difference-between-ps1-and-prompt-command)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortest way is to include a command substitution, but escaped so that it isn't evaluated until `PS1` is *displayed*.

```
# PS1="$(date -R) > "  would include the same date in every prompt
PS1='$(date -R) > "
```

I prefer using the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable, which lets you specify code to run prior to displaying each prompt. This lets you break up more complicated prompts into easier-to-follow steps inside an function.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='make_prompt'
make_prompt () {
   # Just to demonstrate building up PS1 piece by piece
   PS1="$(date -R)"
   PS1+=" > "
}
```

---

For this specific example, though, you don't need a command substitution. There are pre-existing prompt escapes for showing the date:

```
# duplicating the format of date -R (RFC 2822)
PS1='\D{%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z} > '
```

Inside `\D{...}`, you can use any string that `strftime` would handle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable to run a command before `PS1` shows up. For example:

```sh
export PROMPT_COMMAND="date -R"
```

With this in `~/.bashrc`, a prompt might look something like:

```sh
Wed, 17 Jun 2020 18:15:01 -0400
user@computer:~$
```